# Xcode cmd-R shortcut broken

Tags: xcode5

I've recently updated to Xcode 5.1.1, and the cmd+R shortcut no longer works. Going into Preferences I see there is a conflict, but "Run" seems to conflict with "Run...". It doesn't allow me to delete either one of them, and changing one automatically changes the other one, leaving it in a conflicted state. I also can't find a restore defaults option. (This is in fact the "Default" setting, and I haven't customized anything previously.)

I suspect that this is a bug, but does anyone know of a way to get it working? (along the lines of editing or deleting some file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the file:
/Users/< USER NAME >/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings.idekeybindings

Update: Finder no longer seems to show the Library folder in your user directory on newer Mac OS versions. Use the Terminal!
The relevant file for Xcode 7.3 appears to be: ~/Library/Developer/XCode/UserData/KeyBindings

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: @Andy - I updated my solution (although I haven't tested whether deleting this file causes problems with the newer Xcode)